# random query in mysql but show new record

Tags: php, mysql

I am using rand() function to find 5 records from a table which have 50 records.

I want that on page refresh new record will be display.

Like on first refresh 5 record will show on second refresh next 5 record will show and so on.

After completing the record , page should display from starting.

This is not pagination record are updating on every refresh.

Thanks

Comment: You say the "next 5 records" and "After completing the record , page should display from starting". So it should not be completely random? What have you tried exactly? Can you post some code?

Comment: also random records may occur again. what you are trying is not random but yes Pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using the session counter of records and another array for that records , that already wshowed earlier. after the reach the limit - just flush that counters from session.

Answer (score 2):

if i understand you correctly this is what you want:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['page'])){
    $_SESSION['page']=0; //set a session variable if not set
}
//here sql query to get the records somehthing like SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $_SESSION['page']*5 5

$_SESSION['page']++; //increase the session variable
if($_SESSION['page']>10){
    $_SESSION['page']= 0;  //return to first record after all records are done (10*5=50)
}
```

i think inserting the sql query wont be that big of a problem, but an example:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table LIMIT '.($_SESSION['page']*5).' '.5;
```

note that when u start using user input in your sql queries you should use prepared statements.